# Passing nullable decimal from json to ASP.NET MVC Controller Action?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I have an Asp.NET MVC controller action which receives a DTO which in turn contains a nullable decimal property.

e.g.

```
 [DataContact]
 public class MyDTO
 {
     //other properties

     [DataMember]
     public decimal? SomeProp {get;set;}
 }
```

and my action looks like this:

```
 public JsonResult SaveMyDTO(MyDTO dto)
 {...
```

I can see that the js client passes the correct json data, there are values set for "SomeProp"  however, the property is not set when deserialized on the server, other properties are, but not the nullable decimal prop.

What is the easiest way to make it work? convert the property to string?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are sending the JSON data to `SomeProp` as a numerical value, something like this:

```
var json = { "SomeProp": 2.233 };
```

The serialisation routine in MVC sometimes has issues with nullable numerical values, so if that is the case, try converting that value to a string before sending the request:

```
var json = { "SomeProp": "2.233" };
```

*edit*
Just noticed you mentioned this solution in the last line of your question :)

Answer (score 1):

Changing the property to nullable double makes it work correctly.

Comment: sorry but no it doesn't, the binder chokes on any nullable properties.

Comment: there might be some more funniness going on then.  I tested it in total isolation with a single controller action taking a single parameter of a type with a single property.  `double?` doesn't work and `double` works in that scenario.  When passed in as `"name":"0.0"` they both work fine.

Comment: I think the reason it's working is probably because you're using MVC4 or higher. I'm still stuck on MVC3 and it doesn't work.