# Posting JSON to ASP.NET MVC Nullable Short Property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, nullable, short

I am HTTP posting JSON to an ASP.NET MVC 4 web service. The JSON is deserialized into an object that includes a Nullable<Int16> property (aka "short?"). When the JSON posted wraps the value of this property in quotation marks, the value is successfully deserialized. If it is not wrapped in quotation marks, the value is always null.

C# object being deserialized:

```
Class MyClass {
short? MyLittleNumber { get;set; }
}
```

And if the JSON is this:

```
{MyLittleNumber:"5"}
```

it works but if it is this:

```
{MyLittleNumber:5}
```

It fails to read the value and defaults to NULL.

Answer (score 5):

Resolution:
I changed the short(Int16) to an int(Int32) and it will now read the value regardless of whether it is wrapped in quotes.

I wrestled with this issue about 3 hours yesterday before understanding this distinction, so I wanted to post the answer here where it will be found. I believe it is caused by some shortcoming in the way the ASP.NET MVC classes deserialize the JSON into the class.

A related question is here regarding nullable decimals/doubles.
[Passing nullable decimal from json to ASP.NET MVC Controller Action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897988/passing-nullable-decimal-from-json-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-action)

Comment: to whoever marked you down - shame.  This is definitely a bug in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Thanks for the upvotes! I was surprised and disappointed to see the arbitrary downvotes. If it helps even one person, it's worth the time to post questions and answers.

Comment: +1 thanks for the tip, the default model binder certainly seems to have an issue or two and this post sent me in the right direction. For anyone interested by problem we JSON data having unquoted numbers that were being deserialized incorrectly to NULL on Decimal? properties when the value was 0... by using my own model binder and a ServiceStack JSON parser it all works perfectly now.

Comment: It helped me. I discovered this bug myself and came here to post about it, then found this answer confirming my suspicion.